# How to add script/style in SharePoint default list library form in New SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, spfx, sharepoint-list

I am using SharePoint 2013 and i want to customize the SharePoint default list form. Is there any way to add script/style to the form in SharePoint New Experience View?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet. Microsoft is currently working on it.

But you can keep customizing in the classic experience , i dont see it going away any time soon.

User voice link - [Allow Javascript customization and CSS branding/theming in the new Document Library Experience](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th)

**Update as per Patrick's comment :**

This is not available on SP 2013 On premise, its right now only available on SP Online and SP 2016 after feature pack 1 update.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the new list/library experience will not be appearing in SP2013.

Comment: Is it still not possible?

Comment: @AakashMorya - sir, it could be possible(not 100% sure) via SPFx extension application customizer. However, they are not production ready yet. So, wouldn't recommend it for prod use though.

Comment: @GautamSheth thought the same. Currently SpFx is just allowing to work with Client-Side WebPart. (y)